# Difference in Gascost between buying on Uniswap through UI and interacting with Uniswap Router contract on Etherscan

Tags: gas, etherscan, uniswap, gas-price, gas-estimate

Why is the gas cost of going to uniswap.exchange and making a trade (significantly!) lower than the gas cost of going to https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d#writeContract and inputting values for 'swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens'. And is there a way to estimate the cost of one given the other?

Comment: Is the difference significant? Because otherwise, it is just real-time fluctuation of the gas cost. Please edit the question and demonstrate with screenshots.

Comment: It was massive. Like 8x or thereabouts